# Microtypography protrusion with Polish quotation marks

Tags: microtype, protrusion, quotation

I use pdfLaTeX with Polish documents. In Polish quotation marks look like this: „Lorem”. With package `polski`, one can use them in LaTeX with `,,Lorem''`. All was well, but I recently discovered the amazing `microtype` package.

Unfortunately, protrusion just doesn't want to work with Polish `„`:

[image: Actual result]

As you can see, regular English quotes are treated differently from Polish ones.

What I would expect would be something like this:

[image: Expected result]

Here is minimal code example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\noindent
``Lorem'' \newline
,,Lorem'' \newline
Lorem

\end{document}
```

My question is: how to make output look like the second image?

Comment: I did not use LaTeX for 20 years or so but I read this group exactly for that: to learn things I would have never known otherwise (Polish quoting in that case). Thanks for that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `T1` fontencoding instead of `OT4` (default).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\noindent
``Lorem'' \newline
,,Lorem'' \newline
Lorem \newline
ć, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż, ą, ę, ł \newline
Ć, Ń, Ó, Ś, Ź, Ż, Ą, Ę, Ł

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

**EDIT:** This has been fixed in version 2.7b (28 Feb 2019).

---

The default `microtype` configuration lacks protrusion settings for the `„` ligature. You can add them like this (in the preamble):

```
\LoadMicrotypeFile{cmr}
\SetProtrusion
   [ name     = cmr-OT4,
     load     = cmr-OT1]
   { encoding = OT4,
     family   = cmr  }
   {
      "FF = {500,300}
   }
```